# Google App Engine Python App Require Login

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am new to the GAE. I just successfully created a Google App Engine app by following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart. It uses Python and Flask. Now anybody in the world can open a browser and navigate to `https://<project_id>.appspot.com/` and see the `Hello World` message.

Question: How can I add a login requirement? That is, how can I add an authentication mechanism to the app such that only users that I grant access can see my `Hello World` message? Could you maybe point me to some guides/tutorials?

Thank you!

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/authenticating-users

Comment: Take a look into this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/loginurls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are some options available for you to configure authentication with App Engine and Python.
You can configure them on one of the below options:

- Firebase Authentication
- Google Sign-In
- OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect
- Users API

You can access more information and steps on how to configure one of the above options, by accessing the below link.

- [User Authentication Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/)